# Image src in Inspect Element showing up as [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to get the image to show up in my Section from my .json file. So, as always I added a prop to the component and parsed the values of the .json file which is `config.dog.src` . I console print this and the value comes out perfectly with `dog.png` in console. However, in the code in inspect element it shows `[object Object]`. Any idea?

I have tried changed the .json file around, and hard coding but that defeats the purpose of the .json file so dont really want to do that.

```
dog:{
    src: "dog.png"
} 

<DogComponent src={config.dog.src} />
```

Console inspect element shows the following:

`<img src=[object Object] />`

Expected output should be:

`<img src="dog.png" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be missing the `file-loader` for webpack. Add this to your webpack config module section, and make sure you are importing the image via resolvable path and it should work:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png)$/i,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
  loaders: ['file-loader']
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seemed to do the trick and also fix a lot of errors with the other images. :)